# Pairwise vs listwise deletion of missing data in regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, missing-data

I was wondering what would be the difference between using the pairwise versus the listwise option in a multiple regression? 
I have a dependent variable (reaction time) and several predictors (accuracy, and 4 measures corresponding to anxiety & depression). When I calculated the mean reaction time for the dependent variable, I included only some participants that reached a certain level of difficulty of the memory task, therefore reducing the number ($N$) of subjects (from 100 to 70). However the $N$ of the predictors remained unchanged.

When I want to include the predictors in the multiple regression using the stepwise method in SPSS v. 21 (step1: accuracy, step 2: anxiety and depression predictors), when using the pairwise option there are 2 significant predictors on the second model but when I use the listwise option, although the $N$ is 70 for both, the second predictor is no longer significant ($p=0.078$). Also the variance inflation factor (VIF) increases for each predictor (average VIF from 1 increases to 1.8 with the listwise option).

I am aware of what Field (2009), *Discovering Statistics Using SPSS*, Ch. 7.7.6, p. 231,  recommended, by saying that using the pairwise option: "many of your variables may not make sense, and you can end up with absurdities such as $R^2$ either negative or greater than 1.0. So, it’s not a good option". However, this does not occur in my analysis.

What would be the difference between pairwise and listwise when calculating the coefficients in this multiple regression (as the $N$ is the same in both analyses)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Take care to explain the context when asking questions - I've edited the title & added the `missing data` tag. And you don't need to sign posts - your nickname & picture with a link to your profile are automatically appended. Please also define abbreviations & symbols on first use - you can edit your own questions.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to say to give fuller references as well - I've expanded "Field (2009)"